# Dilworth's theorem

Tags: combinatorics

> Show that the truth of Dilworth's theorem for two-level posets can be deduced from Hall's theorem.

I am not sure how to prove this.

A poset $P$ is a two-level poset if it is the union of two antichains $U$ and $L$ with no element of $L$ greater than any element of $U$, so the only comparability which occur are of the form $l<u$ for $l\in L, \ u \in U.$

For Hall's theorem we have that if a family $(A_1,\dots,A_n)$ of subsets of $X$ satisfies $|A(J)|\ge|J|-r$ for all $J\subset\{1,\dots,n\},$ then there is a subfamily of size $n-r$ which has a SDR.

Comment: the Marriage theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A\subseteq L$ let $U(A)=\{u\in U:\ell<u\text{ for some }\ell\in A\}$. Let

$$r=\max\{|A|-|U(A)|:A\subseteq L\}\;;\tag{1}$$

then $|U(A)|\ge|A|-r$ for all $A\subseteq L$, so there is an $A\subseteq L$ such that $|A|=|L|-r$, and $\{U(a):a\in A\}$ has a transversal (SDR). Let $T$ be a transversal for $\{U(a):a\in A\}$, and for each $a\in A$ let $u_a$ be the representative of $a$ in $T$. Let

$$\mathscr{C}=\big\{\{a,u_a\}:a\in A\big\}\cup(L\setminus A)\cup(U\setminus T)\;;$$

$\mathscr{C}$ is a partition of $P$ into chains. The set $L\cup(U\setminus T)$ clearly intersects each chain in $\mathscr{C}$ in exactly one point, so to complete the argument it suffices to show that this set is an antichain.

HINT: $(1)$ is the smallest possible choice of $r$, so no transversal can be larger than $T$.